# How to cancel touches on a child UIControl?

Tags: uigesturerecognizer, uicontrol

I have a view that contains a subclass of a UIControl.

Occasionally I want to add a tap gesture recognizer to the view that should override any other touches on the children views.

By default gesture recognizer should cancel all other touches in view. However, my UIControl still gets triggered. Is that expected behavour?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I haven't found an answer to this particular problem. So the solution in my situation was to use a different combination of actions to achieve the desired outcome.